# Move textregistered symbol more towards the top right

Tags: text-manipulation

I have this as my code:

```
\Huge\bfseries Cambridge IGCSE\textsuperscript{\small{\textregistered}}
```

And this shows:

[image: textregistered logo]

To make it more aesthetically pleasing, how do I move the text registered symbol a bit more to the top so that it is aligned with the top vertical line of the E?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book} 
\begin{document} 
\Huge\bfseries Cambridge IGCSE\textsuperscript{\small{\textregistered}} 
\end{document}
```

Thank you!

Comment: a little more information would help -- like knowing what size is the expression on which the `\textregistered` is placed.  and that, in turn, would be helped by knowing how this text was produced -- is it in a title?  so please provide a compilable example, so we don't have to guess.

Comment: Apologies, yes, it is used as a title:

\documentclass[12pt]{book} 

\begin{document}

\Huge\bfseries Cambridge IGCSE\textsuperscript{\small{\textregistered}}

\end{document}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this aesthetically pleasing?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\begin{document}
\Huge\bfseries Cambridge IGCSE\raisebox{1ex}{\small{\textregistered}}  %%< adjust 1ex as you like
\end{document}
```

[image]

I have used `\raisebox` instead of `\textsuperscipt` so that you can adjust the raise.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version that works with all font sizes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
%\usepackage{textcomp}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\regmark}{\raisebox{1.13ex}{%
  \fontsize{.4\dimexpr\f@size pt}\z@\selectfont\textregistered}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\Huge E\regmark

\large E\regmark

\normalsize E\regmark
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is the output if `textcomp` is loaded (remove `%` in the example):

[image]